# How do I data-bind a javascript array to a list in pure JS without using AngularJS ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript Object Array, keeping it simple lets say an Array of FilterOptions. Each filter has its **own set of values**, together with a **Name** value. I want to beable to Load this into a html list together with **Delete** and **Add** functionality.

I know in AngularJS if I wanted to do this I could type out a **Simplified**:

```
<input ng-click="Create_New_FilterOption()" />
<div ng-repeat="filterOption in filterOptions">
    <div>
        Name: {{filterOption.Name}}
        Age: {{filterOption.Age}}
        ..... LOADS OF OTHER VALUES WHICH ARE IN JSON FORMAT AND NOT CHANGED......
        <input ng-click="DoSomething()" />
        <input ng-click="Delete_FilterOption(filterOption)" />
    </div>
</div>
```

But how would I do this **without using AngularJS** and just using **pure Javascript**?

I was thinking about assigning each DIV an id on load say

```
id="filter-option-[ArrayPos]"
```

However removing filterOptions would mess up the ordering system(the **filter-option-[ArrayPos] ids**) and then adding a new elements would further mess up the existing **filter-option-[ArrayPos]** ids. Also relying on the elementID to provide its position in the FilterOptions[] just seems wrong.

Is there any other way I can bind the Javascript object array to the elements?

Comment: what is the use case where you feel like using `ng-repeat` is a disadvantage?

Comment: @Claies - here's a use case: not use angular.

Comment: ok, then why even mention angular in the first place?

Comment: It would be much more helpful if instead of showing what you DON'T want, you'd show what you DO want. Show a sample object structure, and a desired output (a fragment of the "list" you're after)

Comment: @Claies - it's written right there... "*without using AngularJS*". I guess it's only mentioned as a (awkward) way of expressing what is required. That's why I: 1. removed the misleading tag. 2. Asked the question

Comment: just by mentioning angular, and showing angular code, your readers will assume you have angular in the project, but have decided to not use one of it's features.  if you aren't using angular at all, then don't mention it, and don't show code that has it, unless your intent is to directly ask how to copy their functionality.

Comment: @Claies That is exactly what I am trying to ask. I asked basically how to do ng-repeat without AngularJS.

Comment: that's much too broad of a question to answer here, and could be answered simply by browsing the source.  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js

Comment: Binding is a design pattern which depends on Observer pattern. As of now there's no such thing as Observable objects in Javascript. What Angular.js and other frameworks do is emulating Observable collections that can be bound to DOM elements (and vice versa). If you want to bind a UI element to an object, the first step would be to make that object observable.